# how to fetch and display API content Onsubmit

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-state

I am developing a weather forecast app using Reactjs but i'm having a  hard time Fetching/displaying API data

I know this question might have a duplicate but i have looked up all related problems/solutions on this platform and elsewhere but none solved my problem

```
//const API;
class WeatherApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            location: "",
            reports:[]
        }
    }

//functions should be written outside the constructor method
    onSubmit = event => {
        //prevents default loading of the page when this function "onSubmit"
        //is called
        event.preventDefault();
        //saving the value of the textbox to a variable/const
        if(this.searchbox.value !== ""){ 
            const searchResult = this.searchbox.value;
            //update the state object
            this.setState({
                location: searchResult + " weather report"
            });
        }else{
            alert("please ensure that field is not empty!");
            return;
        }
    };



componentDidMount(){
    if(this.searchbox.value !== ""){ 
        fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=london,uk ${/*this.searchbox.value +*/ KEY}`,{
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }
        })
        .then(response => { response.json() })
        .then(data => { 
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ reports: data.list})
        });
    }
}


    render(){
        return(
            <div className="weather-app">
                <WeatherAppHeader />
                <div className="weather-body">
                    <div className="entry-pane">
                        <form onSubmit ={this.onSubmit} >
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                id="search-box"
                                placeholder="Location e.g Abuja, NG" 
                                size="40" 
                                ref={input => this.searchbox = input} />

                            <button type="submit" id="search-btn">search</button> 
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <SearchedLocation  location={this.state.location} />
                    <WeatherReport  reports={this.state.reports} />
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const WeatherAppHeader = () => ( 
    <nav> WEATHER FORECAST </nav>
);


const SearchedLocation = ({location}) => ( 
    <div className="searched-loc">{location}</div>
);
SearchedLocation.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.string
}


///Declaring state within the WeatherReport component 

const WeatherReport = ({reports}) => (
        <div className="weather-report" >
            <ul className="report-list">
            {reports.map(report => ( 
                <li key={report.id} className="daily-report">
                    <span className="daily-report-day">{report.day}</span><br/>
                    <span className="daily-report-icon">{report.icon}</span><br/>
                    <span className="daily-report-temp">{report.main.temp}</span>
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>

);

WeatherReport.propTypes = {
    report: PropTypes.array
}





ReactDOM.render(<WeatherApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i want to display all data from the API  on the browser console when the form is submitted but to no avail...and theres no error message. pls can anyone help?

Comment: FYI - pointless setting `Content-Type`  header on a GET request since there is no content sent

Comment: `You did not specify your API key in API request.` .. Did you see 401 code response ?

Comment: @ridoansaleh i didn't get a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your fetch call, you are not correctly returning the `response` when you do `.then(response => { response.json() })`. Just remove the curly-braces, that way you do an implicit return. Otherwise, if you use curly-braces you must explicitly write `.then(response => { return response.json() })`

### Working code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.searchbox.value !== ""){ 
        fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=london,uk ${/*this.searchbox.value +*/ KEY}`,{
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { 
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({ reports: data.list})
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually fixed the FETCH aspect of the problem, but it still didn't display the result

Comment: @henrie what are you expecting to see? As far as fetching the data goes, that would work. But it doesn't look like you're ever making an additional fetch call to communicate with the API when your submit the form. Are you trying to filter the existing records? From what I can see, you're only updating the locaton-state.

Comment: @henrie hmm that json object should be available to you once you execute the logic in `componentDidMount()`.. It would be available as `this.state.reports`. If you were to add a `console.log(this.state.reports)` in the render-block, you should be able to see the json data. Assuming that the json/data is in fact in `object` and has a field called `list` which is an array.

Comment: this weather app is to help me understand react state better, so pls if you've noticed any "incorrect" code implementation, i'll be glad to learn and improve on it. But concerning the issue of display, a json data was returned but it was an empty Array which didn't contain the expected output

Comment: @henrie let me try to make you a sandbox :)

Comment: I think i've found my problem but not the solution. My problem is storing the JSON *Array* response into the state...can you help with that?

Comment: @henrie I can help you out. But first, does my solution above help get the returned item?

Comment: yes it did! and i made sure to point it out in the first comment

Comment: @henrie ohhh my bad haha. So now that we have your json object, can you show us a sample of what it looks like, and how would you like to use it in your state?

Comment: I still cannot access it in my state because I've not been able to *push* it properly into the state

Comment: i saw this ```fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${this.searchBox.value + KEY} `)
  .then( response =>  response.json() )
  .then( data => { 
   this.setState({ reports: this.state.reports.push.apply(this.state.reports, data.list)}); 
  });``` and tried it but to no avail

Comment: @henrie woah okay. Never explicitly mutate state by doing something like `this.state.reports.push(blah)`. If you ever want to update state, use `this.setState()` which is a unique method that let's React know that you are updating the state object. When you "mutate" a state-object, React does not register it as a new item, so it will not render your content correctly. Instead, if you simply pass it a new object via `this.setState()`, it will render your new content. Try `this.setState({ reports: [...this.state.reports, data.list ]})` We give it a new array filled with the content from the API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197311/discussion-between-henrie-and-christopher-ngo).